# Mobile Detect - стоит ли использовать

Tags: php

Добрый день. Столкнулся с проблемой. Десктопная и мобильная версия сайта кардинально отличаются. Многое лопатить с помощью css и js не особо хочется. Нашел информацию про класс Mobile Detect, который определяет мобильное устройство или нет. Проверил на паре доступных девайсов - все адекватно определяет. Вопрос следующий... есть ли подводные камни и определяет ли с 100% случаев. Не хотелось бы заюзав его через пару месяцев повторно переделывать верстку. Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Предположу, что автор не хочет делать адаптивную верстку, а просто запилить пару вариантов для разных устройств. Что не есть хорошо или проще. 21-й век на дворе. Уходите от серверного рендеринга.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> определяет ли с 100% случаев

нет. Точность 80-95%

Comment: то-есть лучше не рисковать и писать гору js + css?

Comment: @ПобежимовБорис а причем тут гора `js и css` и `Mobile Detect` ? Он только детектит устройства, а не автоматически переделывает ваши стили и скрипты под устройства

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, вопрос в том стоит ли использовать... если определится верно то я срендерю один html на сервере под телефон. Если детект не юзать то надо писать много css и js что бы было как на макетах...

Comment: @ПобежимовБорис html сгенерируете. но на него нужно будет всё также писать еще другие стили и возможно некоторый.js. Ничего не изменится в условии, собссн

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, вы меня не поняли, симею ввиду что если не юзать этот клас роботы с css и js будет в разы больше

Comment: @Побежимов Борис есть готовые решения для адаптации под различные устройства и не надо писать "горы" js + css, все уже написано например в bootstrap

Comment: как минимум была проблема с firefox под android. С разными другими редкими сочетаниями то же будут проблемы.  Решать вам. Лучше конечно адаптив. Но если что-то уже есть, то можно сделать быстро отдельную мобильную версию, а Mobile Detect разруливать куда кинуть пользователя. Это в бесконечное количество раз лучше, чем ничего.